# How can stand numbers 1, 2 and 3 have the coordinates of 07.9 minutes North ins, but stand number 9 have the coordinates of 07.8 minutes North?

Tags: navigation, aeronautical-charts, inertial-nav-system, jeppesen, symbology

How can stand numbers 1, 2 and 3 have the coordinates of 07.9 minutes North ins, but stand number 9 have the coordinates of 07.8 minutes North? As can be seen from the blue line I drew visually, although the stand number coordinates number 9 is further north than the other stand locations (1,2,3), an ins coordinate is assigned to number 9 more south than the others. How is this possible? Is there an error? Or is it a deliberate purpose? The image is taken from the LTBU airport page 10-9A Jeppesen chart.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mistakes happen, and this is quite obviously an error.

Not unlike your error of including an extra 0 in the original question! - "07.08" ;)

Presumably someone creating the chart was misinformed and simply thought that the number of spots continued by one more in a Southeast direction when they made the table.

Comment: Hahaha I wasn't aware of my error. Thanks for the answer!